# Pull object up with another object in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-collision

I'm trying to make an animation using `jQuery 1.9.1` & `jQuery-collision` where I want to pull an object up with the object it's standing on. The standing platform will go up & it'll take the object which is standing on it. But so far I'm unable to do it. Here are my codes,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    heroDrop = setInterval(function () {
        var currentTop = parseInt($('#boy').css('top'));
        $('#boy').css('top', currentTop + 5);
    }, 50);

    barMove = setInterval(function () {
        var currentTop = parseInt($('.platbars').css('top'));
        $('.platbars').css('top', currentTop - 2);
    }, 100);

    setInterval(function () {
        action_process()
    }, 10);
});

function action_process() {
    $('#boy').each(function () {
        var fallstop = $(this).collision(".platbars");
        if (fallstop.length != 0) {
            clearInterval(heroDrop);
            heroDrop = null;
        } else {
            if (heroDrop !== null) return;
            heroDrop = setInterval(function () {
                var currentTop = parseInt($('#boy').css('top'));
                $('#boy').css('top', currentTop + 5);
            }, 50);
        }
    });
}
```

[**JSFiddle Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/fgovbwak/)

How can I make the object go up with the platform? Need this help badly! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made some adjustments to your code:

```
var heroDrop;
var heroMove;
var barMove;
var coll;

$(document).ready(function () {
    heroDrop = setInterval(function () {
        var currentTop = parseInt($('#boy').css('top'));
        $('#boy').css('top', currentTop + 5);
    }, 50);

    barMove = setInterval(function () {
        var currentTop = parseInt($('.platbars').css('top'));
        $('.platbars').css('top', currentTop - 2);
    }, 100);

    coll = setInterval(function () {
        action_process()
    }, 10);
});

function action_process() {
    $('#boy').each(function () {
        var fallstop = $(this).collision(".platbars");
        if (fallstop.length != 0) {
            clearInterval(heroDrop);
            clearInterval(coll);
            heroDrop = setInterval(function () {
                var currentTop = parseInt($('#boy').css('top'));
                $('#boy').css('top', currentTop - 2);
            }, 100);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't know why in my fiddle not work. But copy the code and paste in your fiddle please.

Comment: This does function as intended, indeed. There is an overlap which seems to be due to a delay in the collision detection, however, it worked fine for me.

Comment: yes, this worked when I copied on mine. But why it isn't working on yours?